# How to store multiple variables in a django session

Tags: python, django, session

I am trying to create a shopping cart in django that isn't dependent on user accounts. I am using django sessions. The issue I am having is that when I try to add a new item to the session and print out the list of items in the session only the newest item is printed out instead of the whole list of of items in the session.

```
def add_to_cart(request,pk,slug):
    product = get_object_or_404( Product, pk=pk,)
    product_document = {
       'title': product.title,
       'price': product.price,
       }
    request.session['cart'][str(product.id)] = product_document
    print(request.session['cart'])
    return render(request,'selling/cart.html')
```

So lets say I add shoes for $400 and then socks for $10, when I print out the session instead of getting both items in a dictionary only the $10 socks are printed out.

Comment: You each time *reset* the dictionary by writing `request.session['cart'] = {}`.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

You each time *reset* the cart by writing:

```
request.session['cart'] = {}
```

You can prevent creating a new dictionary if there is already one, by using

```
request.session.set_default('cart', {})
```

We can even chain command here, and add the item in one line, like:

```
request.session.set_default('cart', {})[str(product.id)] = product_document
```

Comment: But now the dictionary won't let me store more than two items. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Osaro: does the third product you aim to add has the same id? After all a dictionary can associate only one value with a given key. Perhaps you should rethink how you store items in your session, since now it can at least result in some problems.

Comment: No they do not have the same key. All products have their own unique key.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm getting : {'67': {'title': 'hellothere', 'price': '120'}, '68': {'title': 'Morris', 'price': '234'}} If I add a new product the combinations might change but it won't be more than 2 products in the dictionary.

Comment: @Osaro: yes, what I mean is that you add the *same* product twice to the chart. Normally the dictionary can store an arbitrary number of elements. Although it is of course possible that there are other functions that "manipulate" the dictionary.

Comment: The problem is that the items are all different items with different product keys but when I add any number of items to the session it doesn't store more than two items.

Comment: Like the items are not the same at all. I am not adding the same items twice. All items that I am adding are new items that are not stored in the dictionary.

Comment: @Osaro: I've tested this locally, and it seems to work, so something apparently is not working correctly on your side. Can you print the dictionary *before* you alter it, and see if everything is updated correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192685/discussion-between-osaro-and-willem-van-onsem).